# Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0) < 0 $ then there exists a neighborhood of $ x_0$ in which $ f(x) < 0$

Tags: calculus, continuity, soft-question

$f$  is continuous at $x_0$ and  $f(x_0) < 0 $ then there exists a neighborhood of $ x_0$  in which $ f(x) < 0$  .

Is it possible to prove this statement, and if so what is the best way to go about it? Contradiction, Induction, Deduction, etc... ?

Comment: The best way is to use _definition_ (with, say, $\varepsilon = |f(x_0)|/3$) and derive the result directly!

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f :( X, d) \to \Bbb{R} $ continuous at $x_0\in X $ and $f(x_0) <0$

Choose, $\epsilon = -\frac{f(x_0 }{2}>0$

Then, $\exists B(x_0, \delta) $ such that $f(B(x_0, \delta )) \subseteq (f(x_0) -\epsilon ,f(x_0 ) +\epsilon ) $

Hence, $f(x) < f(x_0) +\epsilon = \frac{f(x_0) }{2} <0 $ for all $x\in B(x_0, \delta) $

If you don't know metric space, set $X=\Bbb{R} $ and $d(x, y) =|x-y|$ and $B(x_0, \delta ) = (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta ) $